# script if version in package.json has changed

Tags: bash, docker, npm, continuous-delivery

I have a npm module project that also provides a docker image. I want to trigger the build/test/push of a docker image when `package.json` version changes.

I'm after a bash script that will identify whether the version in my `package.json` has changed.

I can tell if the file has changed with something such as `$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)` scripts that use node are ok since I have the node bin on the build server already, for example, `PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare the version to your current image...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DOCKER_PACKAGE_VERSION=$(docker run my/image node -pe 'require("./package.json").version')

NEW_PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -pe 'require("./package.json").version')

if [ "$NEW_PACKAGE_VERSION" == "$DOCKER_PACKAGE_VERSION" ]; then
  printf "Same version [%s]\n" "$NEW_PACKAGE_VERSION"
  exit 1
fi

printf "New version [%s] != [%s]\n" "$NEW_PACKAGE_VERSION" "$DOCKER_PACKAGE_VERSION"
exit 0
```

Then

```
$ ./should_i_build.sh && docker build -t my/image .
```

Comment: interesting and doable. what about looking at git rather than trying to pull a docker image from a repo?